# Images to the left , text to the right

Tags: html, css

So I want to create a web page where there will be images on the left and text on the right. I tried with margin and text-align but those things don't seem to work. Here is my HTML.

```css
.content {
  min-height: 690px;
  background: url("background.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}

p {
  margin-left: 210px
}

.dog {
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.cat {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 250px;
  width: 331px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h1>PETS</h1>
  <img class="dog" src="dog.jpg" alt="DOG">
  <img class="cat" src="cat.jpg" alt="CAT">
  <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kz0p3mke/4/

Comment: This worked marvelously. Thanks , Roy!

Comment: Can you mark me as the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pull left the images, and pull right the text.
Like this example:

```css
.content { 
background: white;
}


.containerImg{float:left;width:50%;}
.containerImg img{width:100%}
.containerText{float:right;width:50%;}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h1>PETS</h1>
  <div class="containerImg">
    <img class="dog" src="http://fr.chatelaine.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/9fd9bf6740dc9e3db7cb7fd6e682.jpg" alt="DOG">
    <img class="cat" src="http://www.readersdigest.ca/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/4-ways-cheer-up-depressed-cat.jpg" alt="CAT">
  </div>
  <div class="containerText">
   <p>
    TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
   </p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks to you my friend!

Answer (score 2):

Better to use float:left for the image.

Side Note:To get out of such problems learn bootstrap which will be very useful in web designing

Comment: Also , If I use float:left to all images , they just mess up. I will show you in a second.

Comment: this is because u gave a padding of 10px to the top for the image with class cat . so it appears a 10px down from top

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add:

```
img{ display: block; float: left; }
```

This will float the images on the left-hand side and the text in the paragraphs will wrap around them.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code and test in snippet . its also responsive mobile phones

```css
@media screen and (min-width:540px) {
  .div_left,
  .div_right {
    max-width: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
  }
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.div_right p {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h1>PETS</h1>
  <div class="div_left"> <img class="dog" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a7/Toddy_Dog.jpg" alt="DOG">
    <img class="cat" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/disney/images/8/89/Cute-Cat.jpg" alt="CAT">
  </div>
  <div class="div_right">
    <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have added media query for mobile responsive design

Answer (score 0):

use flex layout for this.

like:

```
.content {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 690px;   
}
.dog {
    height: 200px;
}

<div class="content">
  <img class="dog" src="dog.jpg" alt="DOG">
  <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
</div>
```

by default `flex-direction` is `row`, you can change it to `column` if you want item vertically.